# Swift: Skipping first (and more) screens in a Navigation Controller stack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a NavigationController in my app. The first screen in its stack is TermsConditionVC, then LoginVC then MainVC. When I run, it goes directly to TermsConditionsVC.

However, depending upon, if the user has once agreed to the TermsConditions and/or is Logged in or not, I wish to skip TermsConditionsVC and/or LoginVC and go straight to MainVC.

It does not make sense for me to have multiple Navigation Controllers in this situation but I cant figure out how to skip screen (especially the very first screen in the Navigation Controller stack?

Comment: You can replace the view controller in the navigation stack instead of pushing, because it doesn't make sense to keep all the view controllers in the navigation stack through the app life cycle.

Comment: somehow I am missing the problem. Why don't you just push the `MainVC` to the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your AppDelegate.swift file's application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) function...

First, get the Storyboard file in code:

```
let storyboard  = UIStoryboard(name: "your_storyboard_name_here", bundle: nil)
```

Next get your **root** ViewController. In your case it may be the UINavigationController. The root controller is just whatever the arrow points to in the Storyboard file

```
let root = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("root") as! UINavigationController
```

"root" is something you actually need to name in your storyboard file. So go to "StoryboardName".storyboard and click on the UINavigationController. Go to the identity inspector (third tab from the left) and put in a Storyboard ID. While you're at it, put in a Storyboard ID for the view you want to jump to

Third

```
let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("main_vc")
```

Fourth

```
root.pushViewController(destination, animated: false)
```

You set animation to false so that you don't have the default animation show as you jump to that view. I'm pretty sure the user will say this and it'll look like things just happened without them pressing anything. It may put them off

Fifth

```
self.window?.rootViewController = root
```

On this step you set your current window to the root. Remember, the root is your UINavigationController that has just pushed the MainVC ViewController. If you don't set the UINavigationController and you set the MainVC ViewController instead then you'll lose your navigation bar. So make sure you set the root(UINavigationController) and not the ViewController so you can keep your navigation

Comment: Cool. I will test it and then choose your answer. Is this whats called pushing / replacing views in navigation stack?

Comment: Yeah. The Navigation Stack is literally like a Stack as the name suggests. So you'll push views on top and pop them off when going to previous views. Best way to remember it is to just tilt your head when looking at your Storyboard so that the navigationcontroller is on the bottom. Then as you follow the direction arrows, imagine each ViewController being pushed onto the stack. And as you go against the direction of the arrows that's the same as popping from the stack

Comment: How can I use this code inside a regular ViewController, instead of AppDelegate? (There is no window variable unless inside AppDelegate)

Comment: If you want to do the same thing in a regular ViewController then I'm pretty sure the only thing you need to worry about is pushing and popping ViewControllers because all that code above does is what you'd normally do by naturally navigating through your views. So if you were on the 2nd view and wanted to go to the 4th (thus skipping the 3rd) then you'd just push the 4th